# How to get current weather to work with highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working on `Highcharts` and want to use real data e.g weather for a particular city. I would want to plot it in a basic line graph. I am new to using `highcharts` so please bear with me.

Comment: How your data looks like and which type of chart you request?

Comment: We will need more information as there are many weather APIs and flat file sources as well as many ways to add data to the charts (static, AJAX, user update-able, etc). What are your particular needs?

Comment: Well my data has nothing currently. If i simply give values then it will plot those points and make line graph. what i want is to fetch these points as temperature for a particular city in daywise. e.g New delhi city, i want to fetch temperature for the last 10 days and plot it daywise using highcharts.

Comment: currently i am using basic line graph from highcharts and want to replace the static points in data to real temperature values daywise.

Comment: First you would need to know what API you are going to use to get your weather values. That would drive how you parse/import that data to your chart. Which weather service were you going to use to pull down the temperature values?

Comment: I am going to use API from https://api.forecast.io/forecast/87a7dd82a91b0b765d2576872f2a3826/53.479324,-2.248485. with this API, i want to extract temperatures of a particular city on daily basis or monthly basis